# Node.js + npm | Есть ли разница между npm i <package> и npm i -P <package>?

Tags: node.js, npm

Вопрос может и глупый, но все же. Есть ли разница на программном уровне, если пишешь "npm i " или "npm i -P "? Оба способа устанавливают пакет и прописываются в dependencies файла package.json. Но в одном случае используется флаг --save, а в другом --save-prod. Просто если они равнозначны, то все записи "npm i -S ", "npm i -P ", "npm i --save ", "npm i --save-prod " сводятся к одной лишь "npm i ".

Answer (score 0):

[Документация на английском](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install)

Приведу краткую вырезку:

-P, --save-prod:
Пакеты будут присутствовать в ваших зависимостях (dependencies). Данное значение является значением по умолчанию, если флаги -D или -O не представлены.

В документации это не указано, но вероятно, что --save и -S срабатывает автодополнение до --save-prod, поэтому эти две команды работают аналогично.

Возможно, в последней версии npm (8.x) --save и -S было удалено из возможных флагов.